# Pycharm automatic spaces around " = " operator

Tags: pycharm, autoformatting, pep

Is it possiblie for auto-insert spaces around operators in Pycharm?
example: a = 1 instead a=1 to avoid doing it every time manually.

Comment: You have an action called "reformat code", I don't remember the original binding but you can retrieve it easily by typing this action in the search bar from Ctrl+Shift+a

Answer (score 1):

Coding style is supported in PyCharm and can be enabled in Settings | Code Style | Python | Spaces

Use the shortcut for Reformat Code by pressing Ctrl+Shift+Alt+L or Project tool window, right-click the file and select Reformat Code.

Comment: I'm using Ctrl+Shift+Alt+L for general formating. But I'm looking for option, where spaces around operator will apear during typping automatically.